# How to print the same random value as I send

Tags: python

So I did this:

```
import random 

randomname = ['Mark', 'Loan', 'Paul']
```

then I got a site and did this

```
val.click()
val.send_keys(random.choice(randomname))
```

and is there any way that it can print the same randomname as I send to the site

Comment: Bind it to a variable first, then print it and pass it to `send_keys`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random


name_list = ['Mark', 'Loan', 'Paul']


val.click()
random_name = random.choice(name_list)
val.send_keys(random_name))
print(random_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val.click()
# Store value in variable and use this variable anywhere
random_value = random.choice(randomname)
val.send_keys(random_value)
```